# jQuery filter function with $(this).has()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I guess this kind of question is easy for half of you out there, but I'm stuck on this for hours, so, I'll very much appreciate your help. Here is what I have been struggling with:

I need to select all link element that contain an `href` attribute which ends with `.pdf`. I came with this solution:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent().has('ul');
  })
})
```

However, It seems that `$(this).parent().has('**anytag**')` always returns true regardless of what `"anytag"` is (I've checked this with firebug).
So, my code is broken but I cannot understand why it has this unexpected behavior. Could you point me out what is my misunderstanding here?

Comment: We need to see some HTML sample in order to help

Comment: Try `return $(this).parent().has('ul').length > 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) is a filter function itself. It returns a new jQuery set with elements that have elements matching the selector as their descendants. Since jQuery sets are thruthy, returning them in `.filter()` has no effect, as nothing gets filtered out.

You could instead use the `:has` selector combined with the child selector:

```
$(':has(ul) > a[href$=".pdf"]');
```